# Apache interactive mode error

Tags: linux, docker

In my Apache container im facing an issue..!

When i try to view the configuration files of my apache container in the interactive mode. It is giving me error.

The command that i used in my terminal to enter the interactive mode is mentioned below for your reference.

```
docker -it  -d apache2:New
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what error are you getting ?